# Money transfer via Western Union

Tags: payment-gateway, payment

In out site we would like to add an option of paying our customers via Western union.
Is there any undocumented APIs or third-party services that allow this ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Western Union allows API but their API is not for free. You need to setup business account with them, and it roughly costs you around USD 15,000.

Answer (score 1):

Long answer short - Not possible.

Western Union appears to work only with Induviduals (not companies).

Add deposits must be made directly

Comment: and only with companies which are WU agents themselves.